# Changing upload_max_filesize inb Drupal 7

Tags: 7, configuration

Is there any way to change php's upload_max_filesize setting from settings.php in Drupal 7? This used to work for me in Druapl 6 but no longer seems to. I don't like the idea of doing it in .htaccess, because that's a core file that will get overwritten on an upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would change it in the /etc/php.ini file as it won't be overwritten. You will need to restart apache to see the changes

Comment: Thanks, was looking for a way to do it on a per-site basis - on my host I keep the limit to 8mb sitewide but up it for certain sites based on circumstance. Using .htaccess for now.